# If G is direct product of nonabelian & simple groups. Then prove that Aut(Aut(G)) has only inner automorphisms.

Tags: group-theory

If G is direct product of nonabelian & simple groups. Then prove that Aut(Aut(G)) has only inner automorphisms. Here we can restrict any map f belongs to Aut(Aut(G)) then restrict f to Soc(Aut(G)) in Aut(G) this is possible as Soc(Aut(G)) is a characteristic subgroup of Aut(G). Now take any g in inn(Aut(G)) subgroup of Aut(Aut(G)). As AutG is isomorphic to Inn(Aut(G)) we can choose g which has the same action of f in G. Consider k=fg-1 it acts trivially on G. Then take r in (Aut(G). What will be the action of k on r??

Comment: If $N$ is a normal group, then doesn't $N\times N$ have an automorphism that isn't inner?

Comment: Another counterexample: if $H$ is any group with a non-inner automorphism $f : H \to H$, and if $A$ is any group, then $H \times A$ has a non-inner automorphisms $F(h,a) =(f(h),a)$.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of either of the two comments! It is well known that automorphism group ${\rm Aut}(S)$  of a nonabelian simple group $S$ is complete, so the question seems to reduce to proving that ${\rm Aut}(S) \wr S_n$ is complete for any nonabelian simple group $S$ and $n \ge 1$.

Comment: BTW, I think the intended meaning must be that $G$ is a direct product of nonabelian simple groups i.e. of groups that are both nonabelian and simple.

Comment: @DerekHolt: You are right, I read the question to be that one direct factor was nonabelian and the other was simple. Which didn't make much sense but I could not figure out what the OP meant.